# É possivel agarrar em todas as variaveis de um form de uma só vez para enviar para um e-mail ou necessito de declarar uma de cada vez?

Tags: php

É possivel agarrar em todas as variaveis de um form de uma só vez para enviar para um e-mail ou necessito de declarar uma de cada vez?

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>


    <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>
    <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
```

Eu tive de escrever o nome de cada uma

É possivel fazer por exemplo atraves de um while ou qualquer coisa assim para nao ter de escrever uma a uma?

Comment: como faria isso ? echo $_GET; ?

Comment: aparece desta forma :"{ ["datai"]=> string(0) "" ["semanas"]=> string(0) "" ["nome_completo"]=> string(0) "" ["cpf"]=> string(0) "" ["datanascimento"]=> string(0) "" ["mail"]=> string(0) "" ["telf"]=> string(0) "" ["cell"]=> string(0) "" ["nasc"]=> string(0) "" ["pass"]=> string(0) "" ["ppass"]=> string(0) "" ["datav"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(5) "Outro" }"

Comment: Mas assim ele dá me dados a mais :P

Comment: tente usar a função `filter_input_array($_POST)`, um exemplo; `$input = filter_input_array($_POST);` e para acessar `$input["name"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Você pode usar um foreach:**

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . $value . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: isso mesmo,  funcionou :)